# Product and Retailer's Database with accommodating different attributes of products

Tags: database, database-design

I have a database design issue. My project is about products and retailers.

- `Product` table: `product_id, product_name, product_description, category_id, quantity_per_unit`
- `Retailer` table: `retailer_id, retailer_name, City`
- `Retailer's Stock` table: `retailer_id, product_id, unit_price, availability`

The `Retailer's Stock` table links each product with its seller

And also `Category` table with `category_id,category_name,category_description`

Now I want to have different sizes, colour and brands in product. How should I accommodate them in this database? I have included the price in another table then products table because different retailer can sell the same item at different prices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your existing database design already meets your stated requirements.  Each instance of a combination of size, colour and brand in a product is a row in your `Product` table.  This is often called a *Stock Keeping Unit* (SKU).

If you want to have products at a higher level, think of breaking your current `Product` table into two parts, like so:

```
ProductType ( product_type_id, product_type_name, product_type_description, 
              category_id )

SKU ( sku_id, quantity_per_unit, product_type_id )
```

Then amend your `RetailersStock` table to reference `SKU` instead of `Product`.

Comment: Okay if I add size,color and brand in product then I don't get what I want. e.g We have a product soap called Lux it has 3 colors and 2 sizes. I want to have one product Lux.and to be able to get that it has 3 colors red pink white and 2 sizes large and small. Hope you get the point what I want to do.In present case I can't achieve this by including size and color in product table because different size and colors will then be different products. Thanks

Comment: @WaheedKhan - Yes, I understand.  But you can't keep stock on hand, or even price at the level of "Lux".  This is why I'm suggesting that in your current design what you are calling product is really SKU and what you need to add is something at a higher level than your current product table.  Some of your attributes of product move up to the new, higher level entity and some stay at the lower level, which I have renamed SKU for the sake of argument.  If you do this you will still have one record in Product called "Lux" and different records in SKU for "Red Lux", "Blue Lux" and "Pink Lux".

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem with stock keeping systems;  different colours, sizes etc. are usually called "[variants](https://docs.shopify.com/api/product_variant)". There are other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11602955/database-structure-for-product-variants) [on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832495/products-and-variants-best-way-to-design-database) StackOverflow.

There are often two questions that intertwingle here.

One is "I'm selling soap, towels and bulldozers; how do I design a schema that allows me to store and reason about the attributes of those products, when they're all different and I don't know in advance what the attributes will be?". I'm going to assume that's not your question right now.

The second question is "how do I keep track of stock, price etc. for variants?".

The classic answer for this is to have a "product" table with the attributes that are common to all attributes, and a product variant table that has the attributes specific to the variants, along with the quantity of stock and the price (if variants can have different pricing, e.g. a large pack of soap is more expensive than the small pack).

```
Product table: product_id, product_name, product_description, category_id, quantity_per_unit
Product_Variant table:  product_variant_id, product_id(FK), size_code, colour_code
Retailer's Stock table: retailer_id, product_variant_id, unit_price, availability
```

You do, then, need to keep a variant for all products, even if there is only one version for the product, but it's usually a good idea to factor out the "core" of the product data from the more fleeting data like availability and price.