# Database structure for product variants

Tags: php, mysql

I am upgrading a website to enable product variants - currently the website only provides standalone products but there is now a requirement to provide variants of a particular product, e.g. size or colour. The aim is to enable the site admin to easily insert/edit product variants.

The current structure is as follows:

```
table product
=============
id
name
description
category_id
price
stock_level
```

The fields 'price' and 'stock_level' will now need to be relevant to each product variant.

A product can have multiple combinations of variants, e.g:

1. Product ID 5 - Size: Small, Colour: Black
2. Product ID 5 - Size: Small, Colour: Brown

On the front end there are two dropdowns to select the variants (Size and Colour). Upon selecting the required variants, the values are posted to a PHP script which runs an SQL query to check if that particular variant combination is available.

I am struggling to come up with a solution for this. I have currently created the following functionality, which I think is the starting point:

1. Ability to create/edit variant TYPES e.g. Size or Colour:

   ```
   table variant_type
   ==================
   id
   name
   ```
2. Ability to assign values to variant types, e.g. Small, Large, Black, Brown:

   ```
   table variant_type_value
   ========================
   id
   name
   variant_type_id
   ```

I am struggling to come up with the design for the table(s) that will store the product variant combinations (including their price and stock level).

Bear in mind, on the backend, there will be a form to "Add a new Variant" - on this form the admin will need to select 'Size', 'Colour', 'Price' and 'Stock Level' when adding/editing a variant.

Answer (score 3):

I think the easiest way would be to have a Product table; that would have all the details of the variants in it, by including the foreign keys for the Product table, as well as the Size and Colour tables:

```
table variant
=============
variantID
productID
sizeID
colourID
stock
price

table product 
============= 
id 
name 
description 
category_id 

table size
==========
sizeID
sizeName

table colour
============
colourID
colourName
```

So you can get the details for the variants by joining all four tables together. Information that relates to the product in general goes in the `product` table, and you can add extra types of variant by creating new tables and linking them in the `variant` table.

Editted to add:

This way, you'll need to add extra tables if you want to add a new type of variant. You could also get around it by merging all the variant possibilities into one variant table:

```
+--+------+------+
|ID|Type  |Option|
+--+------+------+
|1 |Colour|Brown |
|2 |Size  |Small |
+--+------+------+
```

You'd then have multiple foreign keys from `variantInfo` in the main product table.

I don't tend to like that - I don't like have multiple types of information stored in the same table. I just think it's confusing, and you need to make the programming logic more complicated. If you want to have extra variant types, I'd recommend just setting them all up now - it's a little extra work, and some of them won't be used, but I think it's a lot easier to maintain.

Comment: That sounds good, however it would not allow the site admin to add/edit variant TYPES.. it will only work on a fixed set of variants..